# Tilemill legend persists after unloading layer in Leaflet's L.control.layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, tilemill

Please observe my map: http://bl.ocks.org/GotC/ab8315f6641e841442a9

I have two layers in a map. The Geomorfology layer has a Tilemill legend attached to it. The legend activates when loaded, as intended, but does not unload when the street layer is activated. I am inexperienced in using javascript and my hypothesis is that the .on('unload', function()) script is erroneous, but I cannot pinpoint the error.

Any help is appreciated.

Greetings,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the map's [`baselayerchange`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-baselayerchange) event instead:

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function (event) {
    var legend = geomorfologie.getTileJSON().legend;

    console.log('baselayerchange to ' + event.name);

    if (event.name === 'Streets') {
        map.legendControl.removeLegend(legend);
    }

    if (event.name === 'Geomorfologie') {
        map.legendControl.addLegend(legend);
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QHSQ9/1)</kbd>